# How to have sql Select query such that some columns are left blank in subsequent rows when clos of that row have a duplicate value from the above row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, window-functions

I have a table like this.

```
 Name|  Id |  cost
  ----------------
  A  |  1  |  1000
  ----------------
  A  |  1  |  2000
  ----------------
  B  |  2  |  3000
  ----------------
  B  |  2  |  4000
```

Note: The data is already in sorted order

The result I need is:

```
 Name|  Id |  cost
  ----------------
  A  |  1  |  1000
  ----------------
     |     |  2000
  ----------------
  B  |  2  |  3000
  ----------------
     |     |  4000
```

Since 'A' is already there in our query, the next row should have a blank value in 'Name' and also the id associated with 'A' is 1 which is also repeated, hence it should be blank too. Similar is the case with B.

How to achieve this in a single select query?

Comment: Are going to display the result somewhere?

Comment: case when clause on row number over window on name

Comment: `already in sorted order` ... is the sort order the `cost` column?  Because, if not, then the order you perceive is not even really there.

Comment: This is a job best done in the presentation layer rather than T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select
    case when row_number() over(partition by name, id order by cost) = 1
        then name
    end name,
    case when row_number() over(partition by name, id order by cost) = 1
        then id
    end id,
    cost
from mytable
```

This assumes that you want `(name, id)` tuples ordered by `cost` (as show in your sample data). If you want to use another ordering column, then you can change the `order by` clause of the window functions.

Comment: How do you know that `cost` provides the ordering which the OP wants here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I was commenting on this. This just appears to be what OP wants (it matches their sample data) - of course, another column can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Can we do

```
with tb(Name,  Id ,  cost) as (
 select 'A'  ,  1  ,  1000 union all
  select 'A'  ,  1  ,  2000 union all
  select 'B'  ,  2  ,  3000 union all
  select 'B'  ,  2  ,  4000
  )

  select
    case when Row_Nb = 1 then Name else '' end as Name
    ,  case when Row_Nb = 1 then Id else null end as Id 
    ,  cost
  from(
    select row_number() OVER(partition by  Name, id order by cost) AS Row_Nb, tb.*
    from tb
  )x
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend doing this as a database query.  The result set will contain rows that do not make sense, unless you see the rows above them -- and that is not the SQL way.

I would suggest first aggregation and putting the costs in a single row:

```
select name, id, string_agg(cost, ', ') as costs
from t
group by name, id;
```

If you really do insist on this result set, it is *very* important to have an `order by` in the outer query -- because without an `order by` the results can be in any order.  Hence, I think the best solution is:

```
select (case when seqnum = 1 then name end) as name,
       (case when seqnum = 1 then id end) as id,
       cost
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by name, id order by cost) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
order by name, id, seqnum
```